# Check if element in object is null

Tags: java, class, null, nullpointerexception

I have a simple dataset class similar to:

```
class DataSet {
    private String value;
    private String additionalValue;

    public DataSet(String value, String additionalValue) {
        this.value = value;
        this.additionalValue = additionalValue;
    }

    public String getAdditionalValue() {
        return this.additionalValue;
    }
}
```

Then I have created an `ArrayList<DataSet>` and added a new element `DataSet("Value1", null)`.

Now at some point I need to check if the entry with value `"Value1"` has `additionalValue` and if it does, what it is.

I do a simple loop checking if `value.equals("Value1") == true`, then I do:

```
if (element.getAdditionalValue() != null) {
    return element.getAdditionalValue();
}
```

However, as soon as it gets to the `if` statement, it throws an error saying that the value is `null`. 
How can I make it so that it doesn't throw an error and just skips the `return` statement if `additionalValue` is `null`?

**EDIT:**

But the thing is that the element cannot be `null` at the point where it checks `additionalValue` as it passed through the `element.getValue.equals("Value1")` condition.

```
for (DataSet element : dataSet) {
    if (element.getValue.equals("Value1")) {
        if (element.getAdditionalValue() != null) {
            return element.getAdditionalValue();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: if ( element != null && element.getAdditionalValue() != null) { your code here} ...

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: `if(value.equals("Value1") == true)` can be written as `if(value.equals("Value1"))`

Comment: If value is null, calling .equals on it will throw. Instead call .equals on the string and check against value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/271526/106261

Comment: Based on the above, it seems to me you could get NullPointerException when checking with equals. Try to substitute it with `"Value1".equals(value)`. Also, `== true` is needless.

Comment: Or, if it's the other if statement... if("Value1".equals(value)) {} avoids the need to check for null

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `element` object is `null`, so you have to check it before checking `additionalValue`.

```
if (element != null && element.getAdditionalValue() != null){
   return element.getAdditionalValue();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will sort you out:

```
if (element != null && element.getAdditionalValue() != null) {
    return element.getAdditionalValue();
}
```

Comment: If `element == null` can `element.anythingElse()` be anything but null?

Comment: @Mob no, and thats why shortcircuit compare is used